# How do I calculate a finite-population correction for a weighted sample?

Tags: survey, weights, weighted-data, survey-weights, finite-population

I have a weighted sample from a population. These are probability weights (as samples are taken with unequal probability). What's the variance in the estimated total? All samples are exchangeable (independent apart from the "without replacement" bit -- I'm not stratifying groups or anything like that).